# Scala: method within a method

Tags: scala

I've been playing around with Scala and was wondering if it's possible to *nest calls* (probably a bad way to describe it).

What I'm trying to do:

```
val nested:MyNestType =
  foo("hi") {
    foo("bye") {
      foo("done")
    }
  }
```

This will loop through and print out this:

```
"done" inside "bye" inside "hi" // or the other way around..
```

How could this be done using Scala?

Comment: Do you have an example in another language that shows what you want to do?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen sure, ruby: http://pastebin.com/PugN6fFk

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately my Ruby-Fu is not quite there yet. I'll have to leave it to someone else...

Comment: why the downvote? an explanation would be nice so that I could improve my question..

Comment: +1 as a puzzler but unless you have a really good reason please don't try to write Scala code like this.

Comment: @TravisBrown quick question, how would you achieve this in a more *Scala idiomatic* way (a call that depends on the previous call being called)?

Comment: You could have some kind of action type that is performed only if / after its (optional) argument is performed—that might look kind of like my answer but without all the implicit stuff. It's a little more wordy for the user, but the clarity's worth it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are so many horrible ways you could do this kind of thing in Scala:

```
sealed trait Action { def doIt(): Unit }

class InnerAction(message: String) extends Action { def doIt() = print(message) }

class WrapperAction(message: String, inner: Action) extends Action {
  def doIt() = { inner.doIt(); print(s" inside $message") }
}

def foo(message: String)(implicit next: Action = null) =
  Option(next).fold[Action](new InnerAction(message))(action =>
    new WrapperAction(message, action)
  )

trait MyNestType

implicit def actionToMyNestType(action: Action): MyNestType = {
  action.doIt()
  println()
  new MyNestType {}
}
```

And then:

```
scala> val nested: MyNestType =
     |   foo("hi") {
     |     foo("bye") {
     |       foo("done")
     |     }
     |   }
done inside bye inside hi
nested: MyNestType = $anon$1@7b4d508f
```

Please don't ever do this, though. If you're writing Scala, write Scala.